# ASP.Net SEO Architecture Pattern

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, seo

I come across with a Business Team, for which their corporate site is on asp.net platform. Those folks are pretty much interested to improve their site by increasing SEO Performance. I am interested to know few sample links or articles about ASP.Net SEO Architectural Pattern which helps me to explain  them about re-engineering the site !!!

Comment: do i need to repost this question ?? again on that site ??

Comment: No, we will migrate it.

Comment: Thank you, but i posted also !! But thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably scottgu posts are the best option in order to start: here you can find some of them plus the SEO Toolkit.

ASP.net SEO Improvements: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/05/asp-net-4-seo-improvements-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

IIS!: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/06/03/iis-search-engine-optimization-toolkit.aspx

Comment: sebastian_h - thank you ..! these links are very meaningful !! Can i install SEO Improvement Toolkit on an existing website which is developed on ASP.Net may be VS 2005 or VS 2008 !! Whether that will make any difference ??

Answer (score 1):

*which helps me to explain them about re-engineering the site !!!*

Don't.  There is no reason to re-engineer a site to MVC or whatever for SEO purposes.  Google is great at detecting quality content which people link too.  An extra viewstate field doesn't kill that.

Answer (score 0):

Start here http://www.iis.net/download/seotoolkit for a nice tool to use.

Comment: Whether this Toolkit helps to deploy existing Website which is developed on ASP.Net ?

Comment: The tool is not exclusive to .net apps but runs on the windows based OS. You run it, point it toward a URL and let it sniff out information to help improve your SEO performance.

Comment: Okay, I understand about IIS - SEO Toolkit!! Do ASP.Net Webapplication requires any Architectural Design Pattern like MVC .. inorder to improve the Website performance ?

Comment: Not at all. MVC certainly helps due to its clean url structure but that can be obtained through any .Net structure through various rewriting or routing mechanisms.